# Statistics on diseases and conditional probability

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

I have been given the following problem:

> $9.1\%$ of the population of USA has diabetes, and $0.015\%$ has a neurological problem. What is the probability for a person with diabetes to have a neurological problem?

I suspect that the question asks to find the conditioned probability $P($neurological problems $\mid$ diabetes$)$. But I think that this problem is unsolvable.

Am I missing something?

And moreover: if it is unsolvable, is it possible however a statistical approach? I mean, can one plan some statistical test in order to accept ore refuse the hypothesis $P($neurological problems $\mid$ diabetes$)\leq 0.14\%$ (for example)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I agree ... unless we know that these two events are independent (if they are, then $P(N|D)=P(N)=0.015$%), we can't solve this problem from just these two percentages.  As far as getting some estimate: round up a lot of people, and see how many out of the ones that have diabetes also have neurological problems.

Comment: wouldn't it just be 0.015%